# Status bar Overlap issue iOS7 and tabbar issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am developing app with status bar and tabbar. In ios7 the status bar overlap with view.But fixed status bar issue with following code. When i doing like my tabbar get down 20 pixel. Some of the parts in tabbar get hidden pls help me. Orientation also present in this app.

```
CGRect TempRect;
for(UIView *sub in [[self view] subviews]) 
{ 
     TempRect=[sub frame];
     TempRect.origin.y+=20.0f; //Height of status bar [sub setFrame:TempRect]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my UIViewControllers in viewDidLoad: which were affected and it fixed the issue for me:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: No i have used this but still going my tabbar down 20 pixel.